# MySQL Update Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

I made a simple query to update my table using php, but could not figure out the error.

My Function :

```
function editData($id, $data) {
    $message ="";
    $query= "UPDATE blood_data SET name='{$data['name']}', group='{$data['group']}',
             address1='{$data['address']}', district='{$data['district']}',
             age='{$data['age']}', sex='{$data['sex']}', phone='{$data['phone']}', 
             mobile='{$data['mobile']}',  email='{$data['email']}' 
             WHERE id='{$id}' ";

    if(mysql_query($query)) {
        $message ="Data Successfully Updated ";
    }else {
        die("failed: " . mysql_error());    
    }

    return $message;

}
```

This is what passed in function :

```
$dataArray = [
    'name'=>$_POST['full_name'],
    'group'=>$_POST['group'],
    'sex'=>$_POST['sex'],
    'age'=>$_POST['age'],
    'address'=>$_POST['address'],
    'district'=>$_POST['district'],
    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
    'phone'=>$_POST['phone'],
    'mobile'=>$_POST['mobile']
  ];

  $msg = editData($idUploader, $dataArray);
```

And the error message thrown was :

> failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group='O +', address1='dsd', district='sdfs', age='22', sex='male', phone='23423' at line 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote your field names, as `group` is a reserved MySQL keyword. For example:

```
UPDATE blood_data SET `name` = '{$data['name']}', `group` = '{$data['group']}' ...
```

Look at using [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo.php) as it will do it for you and help prvent SQL injection, amongst many other benefits. Not to mention the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid such code, your program is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Consider using mysqli with prepared statements instead.

As **Matt Humphrey** already mentioned in his answer, group is reserved mysql keyword, but you can use it when you disclose it in backticks like this:

```
`group`
```